# Look for docker FROM base image on localhost first

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two images, first is a simple Ubuntu plus my stuff.
Second one basically has a FROM statement that includes the first image, but is a remote location like: server.com/reponame/baseimagename:latest

The problem is that, that works great on CI Jenkins, but i also want to build on localhost without any CI Jenkins remote implications.

So, how can i force my second image to look for baseimagename:latest on localhost instead of going on internet ?

Comment: Docker builds will always look for local builds of the image before pulling unless you use `docker build --no-cache`. You should make sure it's the same exact name and tag as the server image to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use build args with a FROM step by specifying the ARG before any other FROM lines in the Dockerfile:

```
ARG base_image=server.com/reponame/baseimagename:latest
FROM ${base_image}
....
```

Then when you build and want to use a local image:

```
docker build --build-arg base_image=baseimagename:latest .
```